# Conditional checks in makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, arguments, target

Consider the following makefile.  I intend to call it like "make var=xxx" for normal building, and "make help" or "make clean" or "make showVars" at other times.  When I'm doing the actual build, I need to ensure that the 'var' variable is passed at the commandline, but I do not require it present for other targets such as clean.  Currently, the check bails out  any time var is not specified, which is safe, but annoying and unnecessary when just cleaning or mucking around.  How can I run the check for my build targets only and not at other times?

```
var=

$(if $(var),,$(error var was not specified at commandline!))

var_RELEASE=`echo $(var) | sed -e 's/-/_/g'`

.PHONY all showVars clean prep rpm

all: prep rpm

prep:
# Do prep work. Requires valid var and var_RELEASE

rpm:
# Build rpm. Requires valid var_RELEASE

help:
# Does not require var and var_RELEASE

showVars:
# Display all vars. Requires valid var and var_RELEASE

clean:
# Does not require var and var_RELEASE
```

**UPDATE:**

Per Maxim's suggestion below, using $(MAKECMDGOALS) to check which target was specified and ignoring any that do not require that var be set:

```
# Check if var is empty for prep and rpm targets, bail out if so.
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),help)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),showvars)
$(if $(var),,$(error var was not specified at commandline! See 'make help'))
endif
endif
endif
```

It works, but it's a bit crude... possible to streamline this at all?

Comment: You can use `filter`: `ifeq (,$(filter clean help showvars,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))` then check `var` and fail if not set.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [MAKECMDGOALS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) to find out which targets have been specified on the command line:

> Make will set the special variable MAKECMDGOALS to the list of goals you specified on the command line. If no goals were given on the command line, this variable is empty. Note that this variable should be used only in special circumstances.

Alternatively, you can set all those variables to its default values in the makefile. Assignments to variables on the command line override the values from the makefile. This way the user have to specify the values of those variables only if the defaults are not suitable.

Comment: Problem with that is, I don't want values set in the makefile (as "defaults").  For some targets, the user must specify a value, or the process must stop (and it would be really nice - bonus points - if I could print off the results of my "make help" target in this case).  Other targets however, do not need a value.

Comment: Hmmm but that variable does provide some help... see my modified post with my current implementation.  Not pretty, but it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution could be to add a phony target that checks for the variable in the recipe:

```
var=

var_RELEASE=`echo $(var) | sed -e 's/-/_/g'`

.PHONY: all showVars clean prep rpm checkVar

all: prep rpm checkVar

prep:
# Do prep work. Requires valid var and var_RELEASE

rpm:
# Build rpm. Requires valid var_RELEASE

help:
# Does not require var and var_RELEASE

showVars:
# Display all vars. Requires valid var and var_RELEASE

clean:
# Does not require var and var_RELEASE

checkVar:
    @if [ ! "$(var)" ]; then \
        echo "var was not specified"; \
        return 1; \
    fi
```

`all` now depends on the `checkVar` target, whose recipe is a simple shell test if `$(var)` expands to a non-empty string.  If `$(var)` is empty, then the recipe will return a non-zero return code, and make will error out, with a helpful message:

```
$ make
var was not specified
make: *** [checkVar] Error 1
$ make var=hello
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would also want the following feature.  Only if the value of `VAR` (allow me to change to uppercase, I like variables that way) changed, you would want to rebuild your targets that require it.  Like, as if `VAR` was a file, but it's not, it's a variable.

I will solve your problem with this additional feature.

In this kind of situation I use what I call "dependable variables".  Normally, `Make` uses files as prerequisites.  We can hack a variable to behave like this.

In addition, you will get precisely the kind of diagnostic complaint you want, when the variable is not specified, or when it is specified but is empty.

The reason for the doubling of functions, is because this way it is more convenient for my users, to call the `DEPENDABLE_VAR` function, they do not have to know anything about `eval`.

Here you are:

```
define DEPENDABLE_VAR_FUNCTION

$(shell \
if [[ `cat $1 2>/dev/null` != '$($1)' ]]; then \
    echo -n $($1) > $1 ; \
    if [ ! -s $1 ]; then \
        rm $1 ; \
    fi; \
fi)

endef

define DEPENDABLE_VAR
$(eval $(call DEPENDABLE_VAR_FUNCTION,$1))
endef


# declare VAR to be dependable
$(call DEPENDABLE_VAR,VAR)

.PHONY: all clean
all: rpm

rpm: VAR
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -rf VAR rpm
```